# Why do I have PJL encapsulated PostScript document text files?

Tags: windows, printing, printer

I was doing some clean up on a windows server with some legacy programs and I found a bunch of weird files named after printer ports with no extension.

`File` tells me that they are `PJL encapsulated document text` files,

My first guess is that this is maybe a vestige of a print job that failed at some point, and some program forgot to delete them. Which would not surprise me, the executables around here are usually very old and buggy.

Could you tell me why do these files exist? I mean, I understand that they contain the instructions for printing, not sure if this are actually the raw instructions for the printer or an intermediate step.

Why would windows generate them at this application folder and not in some `printer spool` related folder?

I think that these files should be innocuous, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if someone has set a printer driver to "print to file".

That file will then contain  the output that would normally be sent to a printer, and it can be printed by sending it (using COPY, LPR or a similar command) to a printer that understands it. That printer has to be a PostScript printer and it also has to understand the "Printer Job Description" language (PJL), which is used to set up printers at the start of a print job. The print job is "wrapped" in PJL commands. PJL is used for things like telling which Page Description Language is used for the job (PostScript in this case, but the same printer probably also understands PCL5/6), which output tray to use, whether to duplex, staple, etc.

And yes, the file is completely harmless. If you want to see what's in it, just send it to a PostScript printer. Alternatively, open it in a text editor. The PostScript part will start with the characters "%!PS", a few lines into the file. PostScript is readable text. However, it is about as readable as a program source file: unless you decipher the program  it does not mean anything. The PS commands form a program in the PostScript language, and can include loops and if/then statements.